# Proposal: canonical question for post-submission anxiety

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

#### Proposal

We often see questions from people suffering from "post-submission anxiety." (Not sure if this is a real term or a TravelSE-ism.)

Most of these questions are closed for various reasons -- off topic, etc -- but it would be nice to close as a duplicate of a canonical explaining what post-submission anxiety is and what to do about it (ie: take a deep breath and move on. *Que sera, sera.* There's nothing you can do about it right now.)

I propose creating a country-agnostic canonical question along the lines of "I have submitted an application and am now having second thoughts. What can I or should I do?"

---

#### What the canonical would cover

- Country-agnostic -- this is not a problem restricted to applicants for one type of visa or country.
- Brief description of common scenarios:

  > - I made a typo/clerical error
  > - I forgot to include something
  > - I would like to submit the past 10 years' tax returns to make my application stronger
  > - They asked for XYZ and I gave it to them but I'm not sure it's enough
  > - I did ABC, but should I have done DEF instead?
  > - Others...?

- Questions:

  > - What can I/should I do?
  > - My application is already sent, can I amend it?
  > - I'm concerned that my application is not strong enough. Is there some way to tell if I will probably get a visa?

---

What the canonical answer would (hopefully) cover:

- There's nothing to be done, let the process run its course.
- For certain countries (eg US) there will be an in-person interview during which you can present any additional evidence, correct a clerical error.
- Worrying about what-ifs isn't going to help the current application.

etc.

---

Relevant questions on TravelSE:

- [UK VISA post submission anxiety](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94116/uk-visa-post-submission-anxiety)
- [Clerical error in UK visa application, but form already submitted - what should I do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71639/3161)
- [Urgent help with visa application](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77740/urgent-help-with-visa-application)
- [Could I have approached South African Embassy without going through VFSGlobal for faster visa processing and news updates?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68968/could-i-have-approached-south-african-embassy-without-going-through-vfsglobal-fo)
- [How can I explain to New Zealand Immigration that I am not barred re-entry to UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/99389/3161)

... etc. The above are mostly UK but there's lots more for other countries as well.

Comment: Excellent idea! Usually we close these as "primarily opinion based", but this would be a lot better.

Comment: I think "post-submission anxiety" is known as "[buyer's remorse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buyer%27s_remorse)" or even "post-decision dissonance" outside of TSE.

Comment: What's happening with this one?

Answer (score 3):

'Post-submission anxiety' is ubiquitous in all walks of life, submission of a draft to a publisher, submission of a resignation, a mortgage application, and virtually anything else you can think up.  It comes to TSE in the form of visa applicants.

Lots of applicants have never engaged with a foreign government on a formal basis and many of those people have a very low tolerance for ambiguous situations where they have no control over the outcome.  And sadly still, some of those people don't read the guidance until after they press the 'submit' button.  So they flip out and start wall-papering the net with loosely conceived and sketchy questions. Most don't even identify their nationality.  We have to drag the necessary information out of them bit=by-bit in comments, if they return at all.

Hang around on TSE (or any other forum/site that engages with visa applicants) and you will learn to smell the fear.

In counterpoint, visa sections are astonishingly well-oiled machines, we're talking a week or two turn-around for about 90% of applicants.  So by the time the applicant has hit the panic button and found us, and then 2 or 3 days back-and-forth in comments, they are only about 2 or 3 days from getting a decision.

I have been close-voting 'post-submission anxiety' questions as 'opinion-based' or 'unclear', but I can also close-vote them in favour of a canonical.

**I support the proposal.**

We should continue to use the 'application-status' tag for post-submission anxiety. They are usually synonymous anyway.

Be sure to include the things we need to actually provide a meaningful answer, like their nationality, what visa they are going for, the submission consulate,  why they think there's a problem, how did they discover there is a problem, importantly, has the fee been debited, have the biometrics been enrolled, have they asked the VFS to cancel the app, blah blah blah, plus anything else you can think of to help clarify their situation.

Comment: I thought platinum Mjölnirs were the little diamonds next to some select names and that your Mjölnir was only made of gold ;) But I support this, too.